# Flutter RouteObserver Service - Naviagtion middleware

Tags: android, flutter, navigation, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

Is that possible to create a service class to aware of navigation in the whole app? 
I know how to use RouteObserver and RouteAware classes. but the problem is you can use RouteAware on a single widget. and this is not what I need. I need some class that is aware of navigation and have callback such a DidPop and other callbacks. If you have work with express and node.js you may familiar with something is called middleware I need something like this but for navigation. 
Searched a lot on the net but still not found any solution...

Comment: `NavigatorObserver` gives you all of that

Comment: @pskink I think it's work for single widget if we use RouteAware for that widget. is that any way to create a service class for it?

Comment: what single widget do you mean?

Comment: if you add RouteAware as mixin to your widget(screen) it will only show navigation changes for that single widget. but I want to get all navigation changes on all screens.

Comment: do u have any sample code or tutorial that fix my problem?

Comment: i did not say anything about `RouteAware` - i said to use `NavigatorObserver` and override some of its `did*` methods - like `class MyNavigatorObserver extends NavigatorObserver { ...`

Comment: This is a good Idea I will check it. thanks a lot.

Comment: did you test it before? it will work?

Comment: @pskink you can post your answer to this question. your solution works for me.